# Winamp: Is there a way to know what playlist was loaded last?

Tags: logging, winamp, playlists

I have a command-line script that edits Winamp's playlist.

I want to save the playlist after the fact -- but I can't seem to figure out how to find out what playlist winamp loaded last.

Perhaps if there was a Winamp plugin that auto-saved whatever the last playlist you loaded was, my need would disappear and be covered by the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Playlist Undo](http://winampplugins.co.uk/plu.html) plugin should be able to allow that.

> This plug-in allows changes made to your current playlist to be undone or blocked as depicted in the configuration screenshots below.
>
> To use the plug-in, you just need to install it and leave it until you need it via the playlist editor right-click menu or via the Alt + Z keyboard shortcut.
>
> [image]
>
> There are a number of options which the plug-in provides to help with the management of the undo queue such as the means to limit the number of undo actions stored or the force saving of the undo queue whenever there is a detected change (useful when there is instability in the machine being used).
>
> [image]
>
> You can view the contents of the undo queue which will allow you to see what has happened to your playlist contents by action but also it allows you to export a copy of a change (for those weirder scenarios)
>
> [image]

Comment: That's very close. I already run that plugin, actually! Very funny stuff! The instructions you gave me will indeed help me. 



However, I'm looking for something I can access programmatically, though.  If I edit "playlist.m3u" in my playlist editor, I want the m3u file on the disk updated to match it. Which might be how I should have phrased my question. I might need to re-ask it correctly.

What I wanted to do is write a script that would look at winamp's playlist, and then save that to the last playlist loaded from disk.  So my hand-edits end up reflected in the file I loaded.

Comment: @ClintJCL If it's about writing a script, that inquiry might be more suited on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I'm still using what you suggested, and haven't found what I want, so you get the accepted answer thingy :)